# Allowed symbols/characters in Minecraft chat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any list of all symbols/characters you can use in the Minecraft chat?

Comment: Any answers as of 2020?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Minecraft officially supports ASCII characters under 0x80. It *can* render more characters, but they do not render correctly.

The supported characters are listed below.

`!\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~⌂ÇüéâäàåçêëèïîìÄÅÉæÆôöòûùÿÖÜø£Ø×ƒáíóúñÑªº¿®¬½¼¡«»`

You can find this list together with more info about the possibilities( colors, and style) of the chat at the [Chat article](http://wiki.vg/Chat) on the MinecraftCoalition wiki, if figuring out what these characters are is too much trouble.

Comment: can you explain [ \\ ] please??? is that a typo? or?

Comment: Backslash ("\") is an escape character; these are used in coding when a symbol already has a specific meaning to the program. Note how there's also one on the double quote in the beginning.

Unless you are coding something you can just delete it, and it probably could be deleted in the answer as well.

Comment: This answer may be outdated. Any idea if this is still the case?

Answer (score 5):

Minecraft chat [now accepts 255 characters](https://wiki.vg/Chat#Current_system_.28JSON_Chat.29) (a few still do not render correctly). Navigate to the [*Font*](https://wiki.vg/Chat#Font) section of the Wiki page and click expand to see the full list.

Comment: Seems to be based off of an ASCII PNG file.  If you could find this file and post it as a screenshot, that would help the post even more.

Comment: @TimmyJim aphid's answer is more complete, and seems to include many more (+2k!) characters than just an ASCII file. I don't know if it would help to include this, it might be better to just follow the links on his answer

Answer (score 4):

The current answer by [Krael](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/41649/krael) is out of date and wrong: even the old version contained several characters outside of ASCII. ASCII does **not** contain accented characters. Instead, Minecraft used to support [windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). There are 256 code points in it, of which 5 are unused, and 32 are control characters, leaving 219 characters.

Since Minecraft is an international game, it has since been modified to use a more extensive character set instead. Specifically, the old windows/java variant from ~2000 of unicode, UCS-2. This set contains 64K (65535) code points,  *a code point is not a character*, including what's needed for basic communication in most popular spoken languages. Some South-east-asian scripts are missing and CJK-support is incomplete (variant forms, names, older glyphs missing). Note that not all these code points can be printed as a character; there's reserved spaces, control characters, and a whole host of historic artifacts I will not go into in this post; [Unicode](https://www.unicode.org/faq/specifications.html) is [incredibly](https://xkcd.com/1137/) [complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work). The exact behaviour of minecraft with regards to all sorts of special code points is undocumented.

See the [relevant wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Language). Minecraft has two font files. The regular font, and the unicode font.

The regular font contains a total of 2,374 characters in 3 files, and matches the older bitmaps in shape and style.

The so-called "unicode" font is in another set of files. Any character that cannot be looked up in the regular font files is instead retrieved from this set of files (`unicode_page_nn.png`). This font is less bolded to be able to support more detailed characters such as complex CJK glyphs.

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up, Minecraft has 2 fonts, the regular one and the Unicode one. The regular one has 2,374 characters supported, and the Unicode one is retrieved from a single PNG. Any characters it cannot render will show up blank.